# I have an issue with importing sklearn from a mounted efs and into my lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, scikit-learn, amazon-efs

I have created an EFS file system and mounted it to an EC2 instance so that I can add a few imports (numpy, scipy, sklearn, etc). I was able to sudo pip3 install these into the mounted `/efs/` directory in EC2 with no issues. I have mounted the same EFS to my lambda function in `/mnt/efs/`. However, when I try to import sklearn, I get the following error:

```
Response
{
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'\\n___\_______________________________________________________________________\_\\nContents of /mnt/efs/sklearn/_check_build:\\nsetup.py                  __pycache__               check_build.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so\\n__init_.py\\n_________________________________________________________________________\_\\nIt seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.\\n\\nIf you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget\\nto build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or\\n`make` in the source directory.\\n\\nIf you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your\\nPython version, your operating system and your platform.",
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"stackTrace": \[\]
}
```

I am not really sure what the issue is because all my other packages import just fine. In fact, I am actually able to import sklearn just fine within the EC2 instance. For reference, this is my lambda function code:

```
import boto3

import io
import sys
import json
import warnings

sys.path.append("/mnt/efs/")
import numpy
import scipy
import sklearn //this line is the one that is failing

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    // lambda code here
```

In my `/efs/` mounted directory in EC2, I have the following directories made after running `sudo pip3 install --upgrade --target=. scikit-learn`:
bin                     joblib                  numpy.libs                    scikit_learn.libs      sklearn
Cython                  joblib-1.3.2.dist-info  **pycache**                   scipy                  test
Cython-3.0.8.dist-info  numpy                   pyximport                     scipy-1.7.3.dist-info  threadpoolctl-3.1.0.dist-info
cython.py               numpy-1.21.6.dist-info  scikit_learn-1.0.2.dist-info  scipy.libs             threadpoolctl.py

I initially tried to listen to the advice the error message gave me and ran`python setup.py install` within `/efs/sklearn/` but all I got was the following error:

```
$ python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn._build_utils import cythonize_extensions
ImportError: No module named sklearn._build_utils
```

Then, I tried to delete and pip3 reinstall everything in hopes it would just fix itself (it did not). Then, I tried to add the --upgrade tag so it would reinstall anything it needed to and that still did not work.

I then double checked the VPC and security groups and everything seems to be correct. I have an EFS-securitygroup that only allows SSH access from the EC2-securitygroup, which both the EC2 instance and the lambda function are a member of so they can access the EFS.

I was wondering if maybe my python version could be an issue so I checked that. My EC2 version is:

```
[ec2-user efs]$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
[ec2-user efs]$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.16
```

And my lambda function is running on Python 3.8. I figured that 3.7.16 and 3.8 should be close enough for there to be no issues.

I really have no idea what the issue is because all my other imports work just fine; it is only sklearn that is failing when I try to import it from the EFS and into my lambda function.